# Downloading a video from a php page

Tags: php, flash, video

I want to download a video on `example.com`, but it's "protected" by a flash player.

- By inspecting the HTML code of the page, I've been able to get the direct URL to the mp4 video from the player's parameters, something like `example.com/video.mp4`.
- When I try to go to `example.com/video.mp4`, I just get a blank page mentioning `access denied`. I figured that you need to do a specific request in order to get the video.
- I analyzed traffic while reloading the page and playing the video through the player, and I've been able to get the right URL, which is along the lines of `example.com/get_video.php?param1=some_hash&param2=some_hash&filename=video.mp4`
- When I visit `example.com/get_video.php?param1=some_hash&param2=some_hash&filename=video.mp4`, I **do** have the video playing alone, with no other content, in my browser's default player. But when I try to save it, the dialog box wants to save the PHP page...

How do I save the video now that I have it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this question based around you wanting to download a single video? Without using programming? If so. Wrong place to post

Comment: The dialog box most likely _does_ save the video you are interested in. There is no way your browser can actually "download" the php file itself. It probably is just _suggesting_ a file name derived from the php file name called in the request due to the lack of any other information.

Comment: Did you try right clicking on the video instead of trying to save as a normal page? At least in Chrome this gives you an option to download the video.

Comment: @DarylGill Sorry about that, I really don't know where such a question would fit so I posted it here.

Comment: @arkascha, no it saves a text file named `get_video.php`, which is 23 bytes and contains `access denied (errno 3)`

Comment: Ah, that is something else. So it is _not_ the php file as you stated before.

Comment: @BubbleHacker Yes I did exactly that, I clicked "Save video as..." in the context menu, and ended up with the above result :/

Comment: @arkascha Yeah it's the HTML response text generated by `get_video.php`, I get that, but it's still not my video. :p

Comment: Most likely the "save as" action makes a second request which differs from the first, successful one you tried. Have a try using something like `wget` or `curl` instead which allows much more flexibility anyway. Then compare the successful and the failing requests again on network level.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you I will investigate that!